# How to come out of two folder?

Tags: html, file

[image: Here is the output I'm getting when ever I try to go out of products.html to hom e Page.html]Actually, I have a ***Home Page.html*** and a folder name **sample products**, and inside that **sample products** I have another folder named **products** and inside products a html file name ***product.html*** so how shall I access the ***product.html*** in Home Page.

Like we know that ***../folder_Name***, which comes out of one folder. Similarly, I want to come out of two folders and access ***product.html*** in ***Home Page.html***

Answer (score 0):

**To access product page in home page:**

In Home Page.html, `./sample products/products/product.html`.  `./` means present directory.

**To access home page in product page:**

In product.html, `../../Home Page.html`

Comment: I have tried this but its says.. "Your file couldn't be accessed" :-(

Comment: not possible becoz I don't know how to take screenshots on windows 7..

Comment: 1. Press `Print Screen` key on your keyboard. 2. Open Paint app & paste it (`ctrl + v`). 3. Save it as image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your Home page Is at root

To connecting to root files use "/" it start path from root //absolute path

```
/homepage.html
```

And Another is ,

Use as much back you want "../"   //relative path

For single folder use it once for two type it twice and so on

```
../../Homepage.html
```

Comment: I have tried this but its says.. "Your file couldn't be accessed" :-(

Comment: browser is telling you this error,  is it 404 or something else.....

Comment: Your file couldn’t be accessed It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND